# Run task when android device is unlocked

Tags: android

I am new to Android development, but I have experience with Java.

My goal is to create an application that will try to connect to open Wifi AP when device gets unlocked (after screen on and pin/password is entered correctly).

This would ensure that application is run only before a user is going to use the phone so to save power while not in use. Also other ways of detecting when phone is actively in use while my application is not running in foreground.

My application is relatively linear:
1. Detect device unlocks (user is actively using the phone) state ore some other kind of trigger.
2. If wifi is on and the device isn't already connected to any AP, scan wifi.
3. If open AP's is in range select one with the strongest signal and try to connect.

Right now I am researching options how to detect device unlock state, but different API level limitations make it confusing. I am not planing to publish this application to play store so Google Play's target API level requirement doesn't bother me.I would like if my application could work on android 4.3 and up or android 5 and up if 4.3 is not possible.

These are the options I have come across right now.
1. Broadcast Receiver -> ACTION_USER_PRESENT
2. Job Scheduler for android 5 and up only (also fine by me).
3. Background service. Newer android versions would restrict these.

I am open to any suggestion and information, including problems that might come up in other steps.
Thanks.

Comment: If you create some code by yourself, then you can ask about some difficulties maybe you are encountering. But first you have to build something to start. You will not get design suggestions here, at least if you are at the very beginning of your idea, that needs to be more focused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry!
I already had project created and I was testing multiple code snippets on AVD, but nothing seemed to work. Then I tried to run my application on my phone and turns out everything works as expected.

Class that will handle broadcast.

```
public class ConBroRec extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            //when device is unlocked
        }
    }
}
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ...>
    ...
    <application ...>
        ...
        <receiver android:name=".ConBroRec"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    ...
    </application>
...
</manifest>
```

targetSdkVersion<=25